# Controlling default gateway on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I need to connect an iOS device (iDevice) to a WiFi access port but keep using the cellular data connection.

Default behavior is for iOS to set the WiFi connection as the default gateway, routing all internet traffic there. In my case the access point is a black box device supplying a WiFi network to access it's services, but not the internet.

One solution which we have tried, is to make the iDevice the access point (hot spot) and have the black box device connect though it. This is far less desirable as the black box device has no UI. So it is difficult to setup.  We have lessened the pain by using Bonjour but still...

Is it possible to make a system call (iOS application) to restore the gateway setting back to the cellular gateway after the iDevice joins a WiFi network?

Would be even better if there is some way to setup the iDevice (IPhone or IPad) to maintain it's cellular gateway after connecting to a WiFi access point.

Comment: Are you asking if this is possible programmatically in a single app (Objective-C) or in the device settings or network devices themselves?

Comment: programmatically, but if you could just change some setting in the device that would be wonderful.

Comment: OK, you might want to reword your question then - as is, it sounds like you're asking for network settings.

Comment: To connect to a wireless access point and update it's settings you'd have to be either connected to the wi-fi network or the LAN that it's connected to. Or you'd have to know the exact external IP address of the access point (if it had one). Without that you'd be on the cellular data network and not have access to the access point's subnet.

Comment: @Brian,  yes, the problem is after the iDevice has joined the WiFi network. I want the iDevice to use it's cellular data connection after it also joins a WiFi network. The WiFi network does not provide an actual Internet Gateway.  Knowing the black box IP is not really a problem as we use Bonjour to make that part easy.